# CRM 2011 database query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, asp-classic, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been tasked with creating a report through Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 to look at the campaign management aspect of the company.
Using CRM this would consist of 6 different reports, which isn't ideal.

My question is, is there any way to access the CRM database and pull the data into a web based application? I have hunted through google to no avail and from what I understand I cannot display any external queries in CRM, hence the thought of using a web app.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM is a web app built on top of a web services layer (which sits on top on a database). So yes, you can not use the OOTB web app and write your own, accessing the CRM web services layer. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309557.aspx) for a starting point.

In terms of querying, there are a variety of options, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx) for a starting point.

It is possible to access data external to CRM from within CRM. Again, [a variety of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx), the most common being an HTML web resource.

CRM can also host SSRS reports which is [another option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can query the database directly if you are using an on premise deployment. CRM will give you a list of filtered views that you can use just like normal tables.

I would say that your best bet is to use a SSRS report that queries the CRM database using SQL to get the data you want.

You can also create a linked server on the CRM SQL server to allow you to query external data i.e. from a company data warehouse

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you will have to use CRM EndPoints to get required information.